# How to find all kinds of website tags by python and beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, recursion, beautifulsoup

I want to check all tags' inner HTML text content.

For example:

```
<a>
    Hello World
</a>
<div>
    Wow!
</div>
```

I want to get 'Hello World' and 'Wow!'.

I know I can use .findChildren(['a', 'div']). However, the real website includes many kinds of tags such as 'p', 'td' and 'tr'. So I think .findChildren is not a efficient method to resolve the problem.

Currently, I deem recursive and .find_all_next() might help me to deal with the problem. But I don't know how to realize it. On the same line, I am not quite sure if my idea is feasible or not.

Please give me some hints so that I can figure our the answer!

Deeply thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Use either [`strings` or `stripped_strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings)

Comment: @Selcuk I think you successfully resolve my problem!

Comment: @Selcuk If you want, I think the best answer is belong to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `strings` or `stripped_strings` to extract text within tags:

```
for string in soup.stripped_strings:
    print(repr(string))
```

From the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings):

> If there’s more than one thing inside a tag, you can still look at
>   just the strings. Use the .strings generator.
>
> These strings tend to have a lot of extra whitespace, which you can
>   remove by using the .stripped_strings generator instead.

Or you can use the [`.get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method:

```
print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: This really helps! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = "<a>Hello World</a><div>Wow!</div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")

print soup.text
```

and the result will be:

u'Hello WorldWow!'

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome :) Happy to help